# How do I add the capability to push onto a getter that returns a filtered array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, class

I have class that has a private array and a getter that returns a filtered version of said array. I would like to be able to simply call a push onto the filtered array which would update the underlying array without having to directly call the underlying array. I've tried accessing the array prototype but couldn't quite figure out how to do so.

Here's a code snippet to emulate what I'm trying to do:

```js
class Test {
 _foo: number[];
  
  constructor() {
   this._foo = [1,2,3,4,5];
  }
  
  get foo(): number[] {
   return this._foo.filter(x => {
     return x > 2;
    });
  }
}

let obj = new Test();
obj.foo.push(6);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to either push directly onto `_foo` or provide a function to do that. The `.filter()` method returns a new array.

Comment: You would have to do quite a bit of coding to make a "live" filtered array where updates would propagate back to the backing array (probably using [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)), and there'd be lots of edge cases to deal with.  Do you really need to support this instead of just adding a `pushFoo()` method onto `Test`?

Comment: @jcalz Not terribly. I just wanted to see if there was a reasonable way to do it simply but I'm gathering that its not. My current solution is what Pointy suggested but it requires a bit of rewriting of existing code and reduces my class' extensibility just a bit so I wanted to make sure there wasn't another way. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative via override:

```js
const {create} = Object;

class Test {
  _foo: number[];
  _push: Object;

  constructor() {
    this._foo = [1,2,3,4,5];
    this._push = {push: {value: this._foo.push.bind(this._foo)}};
  }

  get foo(): number[] {
    return create(this._foo.filter(x => x > 2), this._push);
  }
}

let obj = new Test();
obj.foo.push(6);

console.log(obj.foo.slice()); // 3,4,5,6
```

You could also use directly:

```js
  get foo(): number[] {
    const filtered = this._foo.filter(x => x > 2);
    filtered.push = this._foo.push.bind(this._foo);
    return filtered;
  }
```

or assign `this._push` once in the constructor as function and do the same, however this might de-optimize in some JS engine (i.e. v8)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just have a public method, to do that?

```js
class Test {
 _foo: number[];
  
  constructor() {
   this._foo = [1,2,3,4,5];
  }
  
  get foo(): number[] {
   return this._foo.filter(x => {
     return x > 2;
    });
  }

  push(x: number) {
   this._foo.push(x);
  }
}

let obj = new Test();
obj.push(6);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend doing this, but if you *just* need to support `push()` in a way that updates the backing array (as well as the, uh, "fronting" array), and you don't need to modify things with any other method (such as indexed access), you can do something like this:

```
class Test {
  _foo: number[];

  constructor() {
    this._foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  }

  get foo(): number[] {
    const _foo = this._foo;
    const filt: number[] = [];
    filt.push = (...args: number[]) => {
      _foo.push(...args); // push onto original array
      filt.splice(0, filt.length, ..._foo.filter(x => x > 2)); // re-filter
      return filt.length;
    };
    filt.push(); // initialize
    return filt;
  }
}
```

Here we are returning a filtered array with a custom `push()` method that updates itself and the backing array.  Here's how it acts:

```
let obj = new Test();

console.log(obj.foo); // [3, 4, 5]
console.log(obj._foo); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

obj.foo.push(6);
console.log(obj.foo); // [3, 4, 5, 6]
console.log(obj._foo); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

obj.foo.push(9, 10, 11); 
console.log(obj.foo); // [3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11]
console.log(obj._foo); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11]

obj.foo.push(1, 1000, 0, 2000); 
console.log(obj.foo); // [3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 1000, 2000]
console.log(obj._foo); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 1000, 0, 2000]
```

I... *think* that's what you want?  But really I'd recommend against things with unusual side effects like this.  Giving `Test` a public `pushFoo()` method seems to be the most conventional approach.

Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUNaB9AZgPaEBc0AdgK4C2ARvAE4DaAugNxZY7CHnIOVgSQgwAUASjRcc0JAAsAlhAB0BYtAC80JgEYANNABMBgMwGALAYCs7aQF9O2aAHN4KIoQlkqdRqylO3LzIeB6asooqaoQcgdA8fO4KIEjeNPTMLOGssTLQ+MlIygAOlBBy4aLK1WAMzhBpvpmSGgB8AXk40SVlclU1dRDibNAA9KPQpeXQvMIzDArOCuRgINC1DGAAntJ5BSnKEMUgCsDwogAMBvtFIPDkzvIG1aoeyjeMogAemu0-7YZxMMxhMGPAALQfBi7GRgpCUBjkfKFZR3B7yXIyOyYnA3HrlCQjcbQZYKJAKVYKABe8BhcIRSJumIcmBZjjuKEItAAVuFyPAAO5wRBIQmOBIQQh3VGEZyiLnc97EYHEphmaCWaA2LASqXwGVyhWvZVEia6AzGaDqzXazBYI1vKZ9ABswx1wT1BvlPKVhBVZut1gMzpY7r4npAsu9iui-u0+iMpgsQegIccDuI+L6AE4DDortAdDpgWHJdLI4afR442rk1rgwZc4WC0XQ5hdeWo0bY6b4xakxqU87G3mWzo2-aq5mnaIE-mLgWC4YFxcS+2PZ3K4rq73a4P66mR8283OVxaV22O-qK9HjX7dwnLYGD8PoE38yfRwuDEuL44gA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) to push into `foo`

```
set foo(x) {
  this._foo.push(x);
}
```

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this._foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  }

  set foo(x) {
    this._foo.push(x);
  }

  get foo() {
    return this._foo.filter(x => {
      return x > 2;
    });
  }
}

let obj = new Test();
obj.foo = 6;

console.log(obj.foo);
```